# Z-Index does not work properly through animation/transition?

Tags: html, css, animation, z-index, transition

I have a white space, with a grey "tab" hanging right behind the white space. I have animation bringing the whole thing up from out of View.

For some reason, through the duration of the animation (2s), the "tab" is displayed in front of the white space, until the keyframe transition stops and the z-index appropriately puts the tab behind the white space.

I am looking for a way to display the tab behind the white space throughout the transition (appropriate z-index through animation).

```css
.form{
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 82%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
#form-Animation{
  animation: slide 2s 1;
}
@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 500%, 0px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);
  }
}
.formHat{
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
  background-color: #8c8c8c;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
  z-index: -10;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form" id="form-Animation">
  <div class="formHat" id="formHat">This is the tab!
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is non-standard. Your child elements should always float above parent elements. You could change the HTML structure, and make the white bar a seperate element. Then you can controll the z-index properly without browser-support issues.

Answer (score 1):

because you but formHat which take `z-index: -10` inside form which move and give it background, you must create a new `div` inside form

here is a worked example test it and tell me

```css
        .form{
          width: 60%;
          height: 82%;
          position: relative;
            margin-top: 40px;
        
        }
        .form_front{
          top: 70px;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          background: #f4f7f8;
          margin: 10px auto;
          border-radius: 8px;
          font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
        }
        #form-Animation{
          animation: slide 2s 1;
        }
        @keyframes slide{
          0%{
            transform: translate3d(0px, 500%, 0px);
          }
          100%{
            transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);
          }
        }
        .formHat{
          height: 30px;
          position: absolute;
          top: -33px;
          left: 0px;
          color: white;
          font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
          font-size: 110%;
          background-color: #8c8c8c;
          padding: 6px;
          border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
          z-index: -10;
          display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>  
    <div class="form" id="form-Animation">
    <div class="form_front"></div>
      <div class="formHat" id="formHat">This is the tab!</div>
      </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```